# find gap between months in two consecutive year oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, yearmonth

Need to find record having gap between months in a table if the data is present in two different year.
I have column like id, value,month, year.

```
Id, value, month,year
1,  123,    oct, 2020
1,  128,    nov, 2020
1,  127,    jan ,2021
2,  121,    Dec, 2020
2,   154,   jan,  2021
```

Output I need:
Id 1 as there is a gap in month (Dec is Missing for id=1)

Comment: That's a bad way to store a date.  What have you attempted?

Comment: This is just a sample data.actual table is having more columns with proper data

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id, value, month, year) as
  2    -- sample data; you have that, don't type it
  3    (select 1, 123, 'oct', 2020 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 128, 'nov', 2020 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 127, 'jan', 2021 from dual union all
  6     select 2, 121, 'dec', 2020 from dual union all
  7     select 2, 154, 'jan', 2021 from dual
  8    ),
  9  temp as
 10    -- "convert" month and year to real date value
 11    (select id,
 12            value,
 13            to_date(month ||' '|| year, 'mon yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english') datum
 14     from test
 15    ),
 16  temp2 as
 17    -- select difference in months between DATUM and next month (LEAD!)
 18    (select id,
 19       months_between
 20         (datum,
 21          to_date(month ||' '|| year, 'mon yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english') datum
 22         ) diff
 23     from temp
 24    )
 25  select distinct id
 26  from temp2
 27  where abs(diff) > 1;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

It can probably be *compressed*, but step-by-step CTEs show what's going on.

Comment: you are a beast!

Comment: Hahhahah! Almost, @OldProgrammer :)

Comment: This query works for the provided sample data, but not all cases. If value 121 was changed to the year 2019 and value 154 was changed to the year 2020, ID 2 would be returned incorrectly.

Comment: Right, @EJEgyed. No NVL; fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct a date and use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(dte) over (partition by id order by dte) as prev_dte
      from (select t.*,
                   to_date(year || '-' || month || '-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD') as dte
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where prev_dte <> dte - interval '1' month;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd6d465c1f016f0fa9a00e4e431f3dbd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am getting  error ora-01858: a non numeric character was found where a numeric is expected. I am using pl/SQL developer to query. Seems there is some issue due to date concatenation but unable to find exact reason

Comment: @ASHUTOSHKumar . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  You need to check your data to see why you have broken values in either `year` or `month`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the LAG function and finding rows where where the prior month is not one month behind (or non existent)

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (Id,
                 VALUE,
                 month,
                 year)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 123, 'oct', 2020 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 128, 'nov', 2020 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 127, 'jan', 2021 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 121, 'Dec', 2020 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 154, 'jan', 2021 FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM (SELECT sd.id,
               CASE
                   WHEN    ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE (sd.year || sd.month, 'YYYYMON'), -1) =
                           TO_DATE (
                               LAG (sd.year || sd.month)
                                   OVER (
                                       PARTITION BY id
                                       ORDER BY
                                           sd.year, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TO_DATE (sd.month, 'MON'))),
                               'YYYYMON')
                        OR LAG (sd.id)
                               OVER (
                                   PARTITION BY id
                                   ORDER BY sd.year, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TO_DATE (sd.month, 'MON')))
                               IS NULL
                   THEN
                       'Y'
                   ELSE
                       'N'
               END    AS valid_prev_month
          FROM sample_data sd)
 WHERE valid_prev_month = 'N';
```